# How does ngrx store.select method pass the store context?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, reselect

In this [ngrx example component](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/find-book-page.ts), on line 27, you will see

`this.books$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchResults);`

The **selector** function `getSearchResults` is composed of other selector functions and the [innermost selector functions](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts) are `getSearchState` and `getBoosState`.

My question are

- Is the `store.select` a RxJS Observable function or ngrx function?
- How the `store.select` function is passing the store context so the innermost functions can access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` is an RxJS operator that's defined in [`@ngrx/core`](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts) and is bound as a method of the [`Store`](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/v2.2.1/src/store.ts#L23).

The `Store` is an observable and it emits the state after it receives an action and has passed said action through its composed reducer. So the `select` operator receives the state as the value that's emitted by the `Store` observable.

If you are curious as to where the state itself is kept, the `Store` uses the `State` observable [as its `source`](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/v2.2.1/src/store.ts#L20). And the [`State` observable](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/v2.2.1/src/state.ts#L10-L22) is an RxJS `BehaviorSubject`.

The [`getSearchResults`](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts#L130-L136) selector is composed using [`reselect`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). The [`createSelector`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc) function creates a selector that passes its received state to the `getBookEntities` and `getSearchBookIds` selectors - the results of which are then combined/joined.

`reselect` is used to create the selectors because its selectors are memoized. That is, the selector results are cached/memoized and the selectors are re-run only when the input changes. This can effect significant efficiency gains, as the selectors would otherwise be re-run each time the state is emited by the store observable.

So the flow is:

- The `State` observable emits the state.
- The `State` observable is the source of the `Store`, so it too emits the state.
- `getSearchResults` is used in a `select` operator on the `Store`.
- `getSearchResults` receives the state and passes it to the composed `getBookEntities` and `getSearchBookIds` selectors.
- `getBookEntities` receives the state and selects the book state using `getBooksState`, passing it to `fromBooks.getEntities`.
- `getSearchBookIds` receives the state and selects the book state using `getSearchState`, passing it to `fromBooks.getEntities`.
- The books and search IDs are then combined and the result is what's returned by the selector.

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph of the answer. Is the *store context* passed to the lower order function ```fromRoot.getSearchResults``` on [line 18](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by context? The state?

Comment: Yes. the root state of the store which gets splits into two separate state at the lowest functions ```getSearchState``` and ```getBoosState```.

Comment: That's a good explanation. Could you please explain also how the ```state``` is passed to the selectors in the 4th step of the flow? If you look at the ```getSearchResults``` method on 134 of this [file](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts), you will see that there is no ```state``` passed. How that ```state``` from the store is passed from the high order function to the lowest is also a question.

Comment: The store is an observable, so the state is emitted to the subscribers. That's fundamental to how RxJS works: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: I know some of the basic RxJS operations like ```map``` work. In this [example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html), ```map``` takes a function that takes the current iterating item ```val```. In our example it is the ```state```. But I don't see any state in this ```select``` function passing to the lower level functions. Unless it is passed, how the ```state``` can be available in the ```getSearchState``` and ```getBoosState``` methods? Is there any implicit passing or mapping of state is happening in the method calls which I did not see?